# How to integrate Wordpress site post into my site Android app

Tags: android, database, wordpress, mobile-application

How to display website content which is built on Wordpress into an Android App? I have to integrate the wordpress post database into my Android app so that post must be shown in the specified area inside Android app. I am building the app for my current desktop website. Kindly tell me the solution.

Comment: try this https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/wordpress-to-android-app-tutorial/

Comment: thanx for the answer and i will try for sure